# Extracting Source RPMs in debian

Tags: debian, rpm

I have a source RPM from which I would like to extract the source as closely as possible to "apt-get source PACKAGE". What are the available methods to do this?

Comment: You can use `alien` to convert from .rpm to .deb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tool to do this on RH-esque systems is `rpm2cpio`. If you can find that tool for Debian systems, or build it for Debian systems, that's pretty much all you need. The command is:

```
$ rpm2cpio <RPMfile>.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

Comment: Both `rpm2cpio` and `cpio` are present in the default Debian repositories.

Comment: Then the OP should be good to go. That command sequence will extract the source RPM to a directory tree with source tarball and patch files, very similar to what would happen if it could be treated as a tarball and unrolled with `tar`.

Comment: Absolutely, I was just confirming that the packages are indeed available in Debían.

Answer (score 3):

I think these steps will work for you:

```
sudo apt-get install rpm2cpio
rpm2cpio <RPMfile>.src.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

Another option is

```
sudo apt-get install rpm
rpm -ivv <RPMfile>.src.rpm
```

Both packages, `rpm` and `rpm2cpio` are available in Debian stable.